# jQuery animate from 'left' to 'translate'

Tags: jquery, scroll, translation

I am using a life ticker that scrolls by adjusting the 'left' attribute

```
$strip.animate({
    left: '-='+ spazio
}, tempo, "linear", function(){
    $strip.css("right", containerWidth);
    scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
});
```

my question is how do I switch it to 'translate'

```
    $strip.animate({
        'transform': '-=translateX(' + spazio + ');'
    }, tempo, "linear", function(){
        $strip.css('transform', 'translateX('+containerWidth+');');
        scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
    });
```

but it doesn't seems to be working

jsfiddle of the working version + commented the not working

http://jsfiddle.net/fr1cmfv9/1/

Comment: is there a jsfiddle to play with :?

Comment: here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/fr1cmfv9/1/ there is commented the not working version